# Consume my own REST api with Play Framework

Tags: api, rest, playframework, playframework-1.x

So I am updating a Play 1.2.x application with has the following setup

```
- controllers
    - api 
        - Documents // create, update, read, delete, list
        ... // more controllers
    - web
        - Documents // list, read, etc...
        .. // more controllers
```

The controllers in the **api** package render data as **Json** which is used by mobile clients (Android, iPhone).

Now I want to have a plain simple html web app consuming the api. So how can I consume the API from the controllers in the web package?

My goal is to avoid rewriting the api controllers logic in the web controllers logic.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reusing methods between controllers is not the best practice in my opinion. Shared behavior should be coded in the model and both controllers can then use the same model methods.

Nevertherless if you want to do so, you can extract  shared behavior in a public method in your apis controllers wich you can annotate as "@Util" and then call this method from your web controller.

Comment: That makes sense. I think I will just rewrite separate controllers for the web app. Most of the logic is abstracted in the models anyway. Thanks!

Comment: @Regis PS. just saw this.. I still think it's better/easier to have one single controller and two different templates... I'm sure you can do that!

Answer (score 1):

There are not many details in your question, so I do not know if it applies, but usually when I implement REST APIs I let them serve their answers in different formats (JSON and HTML, and if you want JSONP and XML for instance).

The main idea is just to

1. check the request to know what format is required: either using the [accept content type, the url extension, or even a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381568/rest-content-type-should-it-be-based-on-extension-or-accept-header) (and [some more about it](http://blog.programmableweb.com/2011/11/18/rest-api-design-putting-the-type-in-content-type/))
2. pick the right template (or skip a template if you have already correctly built your Json object)

In play there are different ways to do the first part, eg. through your routes: [Request Content-Type in Play! Framework for REST webservices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9675657/request-content-type-in-play-framework-for-rest-webservices) ; there is a specific page on [Play documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2/routes) about this.

But the most important part in this answer is the second point: you should use the same controller and the HTML template should be able to render your page with the very same data that is sent back as json (or maybe a little more)!

NB. if you need to customize things a little more you can access the `request` object in the controller, check what the requested format is, and act accordingly to return appropriate data using the appropriate template!

Comment: Thanks for the links. I will check them out.