# How to handle multiple content types in a single controller action in Play 2

Tags: playframework-2.0

I would like to have a single controller action handle multiple types of requests (json and url encoded value). I have gotten this to work to some extent by pattern matching on the content type:

```
request.contentType match {
      case Some("application/json") => { // Do some stuff with JSON ... }
      case _ => { // Treat it like a regular html form ... }
```

This works, but doesn't seem like a great approach. I haven't been able to get the result types to be different yet (return json when I get json and html when I get a form submission).

How do people typically handle this situation in play. Is it discouraged?

Comment: Why do you want to handle both types of request in a single action? I would handle such a situation by making two controller actions.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9675657/request-content-type-in-play-framework-for-rest-webservices

Answer (score 1):

I think that if it was XML/JSON for example then it would feel less strange then form-post/JSON.

In a normal Action you will have had to parse the body already to get an instance of Request.
This makes what you describe a bit hard but you could probably pull it off creating an EssentialAction that looks at the RequestHeader and selects a body parser from that and passes of the parsed body to callback functions.

If you decide to go down that path I would recommend looking at the action composition part of the docs (http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaActionsComposition) and the sources for the involved classes (you have them in your play installation).